# Strange behaviour when setting property in iPhone app

Tags: iphone

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    PushOnStackViewController *vc = [[PushOnStackViewController alloc] init];
    vc.key = [self.keys objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
}
```

and

in the init method of the PushOnStackViewController class I have

```
- (id)init {    
    self.navigationItem.title = key;

    NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"texts" ofType:@"plist"]];
    self.keys = [dict objectForKey:key];
    [dict release];

    NSLog(@"%@", self.key);
    NSLog(@"%i", [self.keys count]);

    return self;
}
```

But why can't I access the self.key? It returns null, even though it has been set(it is a string).

When I access it in viewDidLoad it returns the correct value...anything I haven't read, or am I doing anything wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: One big problem in your code is that you usually first init the superclass, i.e. use if((self = [super init])) { ... } return self; to wrap the code in your init method. Otherwise, things might not have correctly been set up as they should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access self.key inside the -init function because at that point it hasn't been set yet. you are setting it afterwards:

```
PushOnStackViewController *vc = [[PushOnStackViewController alloc] init]; // init runs here.
vc.key = [self.keys objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]; // but you don't set the key property until here.
```

You might try adding a "key" parameter to the init function, like so:

```
-(id)initWithKey:(NSString*)key {
   self = [super init];
   if (self) {
      self.key = key;
      ...etc...
   }
   return self;
}
```

Comment: `initWithNibNamed:` is the designated initializer for `UIViewController`, so if you want to add a custom initializer, you need to either override that, or otherwise make sure it gets called.

Answer (score 0):

Your init method is called before you set the property. Get rid of that init method and move your code into `viewDidLoad` to ensure that it's called after you've done all the property setup.

Don't create new init method for a `UIViewController` unless you know what you're doing. It's much easier to create a property (like you've done) and access that property inside the `viewDidLoad` method.